# How to print text lines in a textbox before using Append.Text in windows form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to add the contents of my five text boxes in the form to a multi line text box named "TextBox1". However, everytime I change the content of my textboxes, instead of adding another line with the contents it replaces the pre-existing line. How do I make the next line print.

```
     Dim Newline As String
    Newline = System.Environment.NewLine

    TextBox1.Text = "Plane Truss"
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Newline & "JointCoordinates"
    TextBox1.AppendText(Newline & Joint# & " " & coordinates1 & " " & bc1 & " " & jointloads1 & " " & settlements1 & " " & jointrotation1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can convert the whole multiline text box into a .txt
>   file?

Sure...use the Lines() property of the TextBox and File.WriteAllLines():

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("c:\some path\folder\file.txt", Result1.Lines)
```